# c# attribute Display why we use them?

Tags: c#

this code

```
[Display(Name="Name")]
public string StudentName { get; set; }
```

why use the Display attribute and how i can use them ? for what !

Answer (score 3):

The Display attribute is used to modify the text that displays on the screen when a control is rendered for your view.

For example (in your view CSHTML file):

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.StudentName)
```

Will display a label with the text "Name" because of the Display attribute in your example, rather than the default value of "Student Name" had you not included the attribute.  This is also true of validation messages.

See "Remarks" here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think the main use is for localization support. Whenever localizing an application, i.e., providing multiple language support, the same field should have its text rendered differently according to the language currently in use in the application. For instance, the field Student will have different texts when the application is run in English, Swedish and Hebrew.